# How to add keypress event to div with 'contenteditable' attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hi I have created a textarea from a div using -webkit-appearnce. Now I want to add an event to this div on key press. I try my best to do this but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Please take a look at code and let me know what wrong in this

**CSS:**

```
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;    
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="input" contenteditable>I look like an input</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#input').unbind().on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Your event executes when the user hits `Enter`. Do you not want a newline to appear as well as the alert to show up?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine. Try to press enter so that it will alert . You are checking whether enter key is pressed `if (e.which == 13)`  . You can remove that conditional statement for any key press.

> Refer : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q94hsaks/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look following snippet.

```js
$('#input').on('keypress', function(e) {
       alert('hello');
});
```

```css
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="input" contenteditable>
  I look like an input
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as intended when I try it in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuyk5xyb/3/). Your code will **only** run when you press `Enter` and it will create a new line below the existing text, as well as show the `alert()`. However, if what you intended was not to create a new line but only show a message when your user hits `Enter`, use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zuyk5xyb/). If what you intended was to only greet the user once, use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zuyk5xyb/2/). Finally if you wanted to never allow the user to write text but just show him the alert, use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zuyk5xyb/1/).

Comment: okay what I have to create this text area dynamically and hit enter event??

Comment: @AzadChouhan Supposing you create this text-area with the right id, you can just use `$('#input').on('keypress', ...)` to make the text-area respond to the user input however you want. The code sample you provided us with required the user to specifically press `Enter` inside the area to show an `alert()`. You did not specify exactly what you wanted, so I went on to showcase what your code did, what it should do imho (not create a newline) and what other options you have regarding what you might want to do with your text-area and the message based on my understanding of your code.